# "puppet apply" and executing resources on client

Tags: puppet

I have a quick question: is there any way to exec command via puppet on the client machine with "puppet apply" to create custom resource?

I was trying to do it as bellow:

```
puppet apply --config=/etc/puppet/puppet.conf -e "jboss::apps {'appname': filename=> 'file-1.0',}"
```

After applying above command I am getting following error:

```
Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type jboss::apps at line 1 on node fqdn.client
```

I was able to run this command on the master with "--catalog catalog.json" option but I don't have a catalog on the client.

I don't want to copy manifests/modules on the client machine but use puppet master to serve the files.

Kind regards,

Michal.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, puppet has to know what to do. If you really want to use `puppet apply`, intead of the more comment `puppet agent`, you can either :

- give it a "high level" description of what you want (using the `jboss::apps` defined type), and include a description of what it is (by including the corresponding `modules` on the client)
- provide a full breakdown of the operations in "native types", by copying the json catalog on the client, and executing it with the `--catalog` option (don't forget to set the puppet server if you want files served)

Comment: Thanks for your reply bartavelle. Do you know if there is a "proper"/"puppet" way of sending json catalog to the client?

Comment: I don't think there is, but I would just `scp` them. And shameless promotion : you can generate your json files much faster with [language puppet](http://lpuppet.banquise.net).